# union rows with intersecting values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am working with a tibble that looks like:

```
tibble(id = list(c(1, 3), c(2, 3), c(1, 3), c(1, 2), c(4, 5)))
```

I would like to union rows with intersecting values and drop used rows.

In this case, should give result of:

```
tibble(id = list(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5)))
```

Comment: What if you had `df1 <- tibble(id = list(c(1, 3), c(2, 3), c(1, 3), c(1,2) ,c(4, 5)))` (notice the extra row: `c(1, 2)`); would the result be the same for this as well?

Comment: Yes the result would be the same.

Comment: If you can reshape this into an unnested data frame with two columns, you could use `igraph::graph_from_edgelist` to make a network, and then `max_cliques` to find maximal cliques, aka complete subgraphs. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997146/r-igraph-find-all-maximal-cliques-without-overlapping